# id3 tags and the APIC tag in particular

Tags: mp3, id3

Please forgive my misuse of nomenclature since I'm still finding my way around. I don't know if I have "mp3 tags" or "id3 tags", and if I have "id3 tags" what the "v" means, or even if there is any distinction among these terms.

I have a few audio tracks, and I have learned that when I listen to them in a media player, I often have the opportunity to "update information", which means update the mp3 tags from a database, usually "MusicBrainz". There are utilities to get/set values for these tags, and for the most part the process is quite straight-forward. I have been using "mid3v2" on Fedora.

Now, about the APIC tag, ...

If my media player updates the mp3 tags, I will get **two** AlbumArt_{}_.jpg" image files, one 200x200 ="Large", and one 75x75 ="Small", which raises the questions, "Why two?", and "Can I have two values for the APIC tag?", and "How do I set this tag?", and "Where can I find examples?".

I have successfully used "mid3v2" to set tag values, and "mid3v2 -f" to read tag values, but the APIC tag is different, if only because it seems to have a much more complicated specification discipline. Reading APIC doesn't tell me much.

Can anybody clear up my APIC confusion? Maybe a few examples?

Thanks for the help,

Chris.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't know if I have "mp3 tags" or "id3 tags", and if I have "id3 tags" what the "v" means, or even if there is any distinction among these terms.

ID3 is practically the only standard for tagging MP3 files, so the two terms are mostly interchangeable. Usually they're called ID3 tags though, as it *is* a separate standard (invented by various MP3 player apps) rather than being properly built into the format – and because some other non-MP3 formats may, very rarely, use ID3 tags as well.

ID3v1 (i.e. *version 1* of the tagging format) was very limited, with only a few fixed-size fields for artist/album/title (and a fixed list of genres to choose from).

Everything was completely reworked in ID3v2 (version 2) to allow an MP3 file to contain any number of tag/value fields (roughly what you see in `mid3v2`).

You can still find older mp3 files that have both a v1 and v2 tag (from the early days when v2 was still new), though nowadays there is no reason to use v1 anymore.

ID3v2 has a few sub-versions; the most common ones are v2.3 and v2.4 – the latter isn't as universally supported as v2.3 is (e.g. Windows Explorer only started recognizing it last year or so), but Mutagen will upgrade all your files to v2.4 anyway.

> If my media player updates the mp3 tags, I will get two AlbumArt_{}_.jpg" image files, one 200x200 ="Large", and one 75x75 ="Small", which raises the questions, "Why two?", and "Can I have two values for the APIC tag?", and "How do I set this tag?", and "Where can I find examples?".

The "AlbumArt*.jpg" files are specific to Windows Media Player – it uses those files as a kind of cache, either to store downloaded album art before writing it to file tags, or to avoid needing to read embedded tags at all.

"Why two?" – because the developers of Windows Media Player needed two, for some reason. These files have no relationship to how the covers are actually stored in ID3 tags.

"Can I have two values for the APIC tag?" – yes, but this ability is meant for storing several *different* covers (e.g. front cover, back cover, lyrics booklet, disc itself) rather than different sizes of the same cover. The [ID3v2.4 standard tag spec](https://id3.org/id3v2.4.0-frames) (section 4.14) talks about this.

"How do I set this tag?" – use the `-p/--picture` option of mid3v2, or write a custom script using Python's `mutagen` module, or import the covers using a media player that supports this. Foobar2000 lets you add multiple cover images; many other players generally support adding *at least* one front cover.

```
mid3v2 -p "cover.jpg:cover:3:image/jpeg" foo.mp3
```

Here `3` is mutagen.id3.PictureType.COVER_FRONT, while `cover` is the image's "description". Confusingly, mutagen allows multiple APIC frames with the same type – which most players won't display correctly – but at the same time insists on the description being unique, so if you add a new image with the description "cover" it will overwrite a previous image of the same description.

(I really get the feeling that mutagen has the type and description fields accidentally swapped. In fact, even mid3v2's "Invalid picture type" error message refers to the wrong field – mid3v2 uses the 3rd field as the type, but the error message shows the 2nd instead.)

```python
with open("cover.jpg", "rb") as fh:
    apic = mutagen.id3.APIC(data=fh.read(),
                            type=mutagen.id3.PictureType.COVER_FRONT,
                            desc="cover",
                            mime="image/jpeg")
tags = mutagen.mp3.MP3("foo.mp3")
tags.add(apic)
tags.save()
```

Comment: That is possibly the most helpful, useful and comprehensive answer to any question I have ever gotten! O.M.G., if only all questions could receive such diligent attention! Thanks very much for the help.

Comment: I can successfully add APIC entries, but they seem to *accumulate*! This means that I have "artifacts", meaning "wrong" values. Is there a way to delete all APIC entries, so I can start over?

Comment: `mid3v2 --delete-frames=APIC` or `del tags["APIC:some description"]` should work. mid3v2 also seems to replace APIC frames if they have the same description.

Comment: Yes. That worked. Thanks for the help. Again.

Comment: I have a multi-album collection that is tagged with multiple entries for each track sequence -- six "Track 1", six "Track 2", ... I researched the albums in the collection and "serialized" the albums -- "01", "02, ... and I tagged the tracks "0101", "0102", ... You can guess the problem -- octal numbers in Python. I know that "0x..." would be hex, but I don't know how to force a string to be interpreted as decimal. I have a few options: "0d..." ? or maybe "0101.0", "0102.0", ... Any advice?

Comment: That highly depends on where the strings are being interpreted. Is mutagen _reading_ string tag values and interpreting them as octal integers, or are you using `range(0101, 0109)`" in your code and having Python misinterpret them as octal _before_ passing to mutagen, or are you getting the numbers as strings from somewhere and then using `int(..)` on them, or what?

Comment: I am doing this: mid3v2 --TRCK "0101" --or-- mid3v2 --TRCK ""0109". In the first case I see track "65" in the media player and in the second case I see track "109". Since there are a few layers, and it is not clear to me who is doing what, although I could possibly answer this question by advanced guessing, but it is always better to ask those who know.

Comment: If mid3v2 is converting your input to an integer, you _could_ edit the script to make it always use decimal as the base (e.g. if it calls `int(x)` change it to `int(x, 10)`) – but it would likely be easier to just call mid3v2 with `--TRCK 109` without specifying the leading zeros in the first place, because it'll be stored as the same kind of number anyway. (If you're scripting mid3v2 in Bash, then `shopt -s extglob; x=${x##+(0)}` is one of several ways to chop off all leading zeros from $x.)

Comment: Ha! You know what worked? Simply removing the leading zeros! I have a gift for creating complexity and I didn't think of this; it was suggested by a kid before I read your equally salient advice above. I have successfully completed this project and I wouldn't have been able to so so without your generous assistance. Thanks very much.